# Spark set S3 object metadata while writing to EMRFS

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I have Spark working on EMR, writting JSON files to S3 through EMRFS:

```
dataframe
  .coalesce(1)
  .write()
  .option("compression", "gzip")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .json(outputPath);
```

The problem is that the output file contains only one header
`Content-Type = application/octet-stream`. And lacks another `Content-Encoding = gzip`.

*How can I set metadata `Content-Encoding = gzip` to the output file while writing it with Spark?*

Answer (score -2):

You could also use options(Map)

val metadataoptions = Map("compression" -> "gzip", "Content-Language" -> "US-En");

dataframe.coalesce(1).write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).options(metadataoptions).json(outputPath);

You need to import 
import scala.collection.Map;