# Set S3 object metadata (tag) when writing RDD to S3 with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, metadata, rdd

Is there a way to set an S3 Object's metadata (I want to set the tag) when writing an RDD to S3 from Spark? The examples that I find (such as [Amazon's](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-s3-tagging-spark-util) and [Spark set S3 object metadata while writing to EMRFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53641289/spark-set-s3-object-metadata-while-writing-to-emrfs)) are for DataFrames, not RDDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in the s3a codebase as of March 9, 2021. no idea about EMR's s3 connector

*update Feb 2023*. Hadoop 3.3.5+ s3a connector

- lets you set headers using the `createFile()` builder API (not through RDD API unless someone wires it up)
- has the option `fs.s3a.object.content.encoding` to set the encoding ... set it through spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.object.content.encoding to be picked up on all files [HADOOP-17851](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-17851)

Before anyone asks "will this be backported?" the answer is: Not by the hadoop developers. Everyone is free to make their private forks of old releases and cherrypick whatever they want, but don't expect others to do it for you.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the case, confirmed by Amazon.

Comment: well, s3a project will take a PR, with tests. No reason to stop anyone doing it. Hadoop .3.3.1 will let you query any header through the existing XAttr API (e.e. getXAttr("header.etag"); but the setXAttr call is no use as it can only be invoked after the file is written. We'd need to add createFile() options, and move Spark over to using that API To write files -or at least the parquet lib

Comment: Use, but I'm using EMR, which is using Amazon's s3 connector.

Comment: Well, afraid their S3 connector is closed. Like I said: we'll take changes in the ASF one if you can come up with a nice story for how to wire it through spark. Would it work if every object in your spark job (i.e. with the same config) had the same set of tags? That'd be the easiest. Trying do it for individual RDDs would be more complex

Comment: Our use case is that we're writing out millions of objects every Spark run and we want them to get set with a tag which makes them get automatically deleted in 7 days unless we explicitly want to keep them (which we would do by removing the tag). Spark is not good about cleaning up after itself, and S3 object deletion is slow...

Comment: But we are a pure RDD application, as we are storing complex python objects in the RDDs and write them out as pickles.

Comment: Afraid you will probably have to resort to the AWS S3 API and add tags yourselves on newly created files.

Comment: It's true! Although we could create a lambda rule that looks at access logs and adds them automatically. Annoyingly, there is no way to ask S3 to just log writes.

Comment: "Annoyingly, there is no way to ask S3 to just log writes.". Wait till you try to debug race conditions across clusters. You'll appreciate the full logs. Remember to look for multipart uploads as well as simple PUT requests...renames and large files are multipart

Comment: Yes, I have spent a considerable amount of time debugging s3 race conditions. I especially like the function call that waits for an object to appear and doesn't return until it does, and that provides no return codes.

Comment: which function call?

Comment: we are using `saveAsPickleFile`

Comment: oh, that's python APIs. not my world. Sorry

Comment: same problem with the `saveAsTextFile`. It writes out thousands of part files. We want the part files to be automatically deleted according to our AWS lifecycle policy. The only way to do that is to have them written under a specific prefix or to give them a tag.

Comment: By "s3a codebase" do you mean the [`S3AFileSystem`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/ecb9f817ac416493928989776792fd3e7753e268/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/S3AFileSystem.java#L177) class and related code in the [`org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a` package](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/tree/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a)?

Answer (score 0):

This solution looks like vandalism and can hardly be used in production, but it works for Dataset and theoretically should work for RDD.

1. Go to your EMR Cluster Master node and download /lib/spark/jars/emrfs-hadoop-assembly-2.50.0.jar
2. Add that lib to /libs directory in your Spark application
3. Change build.gradle to

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '8.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

jar.enabled = false

version = '0.0.DEBUG'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1-emr-artifacts/emr-6.6.0/repos/maven/'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

ext['aws_version'] = '1.12.170'
// For emr spark and hadoop versions please refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-650-release.html
//https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/us-east-1-emr-artifacts?prefix=emr-6.6.0/repos/maven/org/apache/hadoop/&region=us-east-1
ext['hadoop_version'] = '3.2.1-amzn-6'
ext['spark_version'] = '3.2.0'

task unzipEmrHadoopAssembly(type: Copy) {
    from zipTree('libs/emrfs-hadoop-assembly-2.50.0.jar')
    into("$buildDir/libs/emrfs-hadoop-assembly")
    include "**/*"
    exclude "**/S3ObjectRequestFactory.class"
}

dependencies {
    shadow("org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:$spark_version")
    shadow("org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:$spark_version")

    shadow("org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:$hadoop_version")
    shadow("org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:$hadoop_version")
    shadow("org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:$hadoop_version")

    //lib from the cluster from /lib/spark/jars/emrfs-hadoop-assembly-2.50.0.jar
    implementation files("$buildDir/libs/emrfs-hadoop-assembly") {
        builtBy 'unzipEmrHadoopAssembly'
    }

    testImplementation('junit:junit:4.12')
}

assemble.dependsOn shadowJar

shadowJar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.mycompany.Runner'
        )
    }
    relocate("com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs", "com.amazon.mycompany.emr.hadoop.fs")
    archiveFileName = "${project.name}-${project.version}.jar"
}
```

4. Create class `com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.S3ObjectRequestFactory` and change methods `newPutObjectRequest`, `newCopyObjectRequest`, `newMultipartUploadRequest` to set tags to your S3 object.
5. Use `sparkConf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3.impl", "com.amazon.mycompany.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem")` when you need to create S3 files with tags.
6. When you run your job, use --jar to include your new Hadoop File System to Class Path. Better to create a separate jar that will be a full copy of emrfs-hadoop-assembly-2.50.0.jar but will set a tag to your S3 object.

Comment: yeah, that's vandalism. If you are doing that, you would maybe be safer forking the aws sdk and patching it there instead -as that is on github for you to edit

Comment: I wasn't able to find the emrfs-hadoop-assembly, is it on github?

Comment: no, aws-sdk-java is on github. emr is closed source